# How to implement a 4 quadrant atan2 function in gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio, gnuradio-companion

I have recently begun experimenting with SDR and have been using the GNU Radio platform.

More specifically the 'gnuradio-companion' graphical interface.

I have a need to determine a 4 quadrant arcTangent function and have run into some trouble.  Within a 'GRC' file I have been able to successfully evaluate an ATAN function but, although python supports ATAN2, I have not been able to figure out how to implement this function.

I have read that there is a lookup table function included in GNU Radio called fast_atan2f but I do not know if this is accessible from within the blocks contained in the standard gnuradio-companion setup.  I was able to access the python expression 'math.atan2(arg1,arg2)' from within a constant source block but I don't need this as a constant value, I'm looking for a block with two floating point inputs (or a single complex input) that will fit within a flow graph to properly evaluate the ATAN2 function.

I have included a sample 'GRC' file that may help to illustrate the issue in case my description is unclear.

[link to the GNU Radio companion example file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70919242/tangetTest.grc)

[image: Screenshot of the Flow Graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block `gnuradio.blocks.complex_to_arg` (*Complex to Arg* in GRC) is an atan2 operation.

If you need two separate floating point inputs as you described, then just precede it with a *Float To Complex* block.

Depending on your specific application, you may also be interested in `gnuradio.analog.quadrature_demod` (*Quadrature Demod* in GRC). This block produces essentially the *derivative* of atan2, but without any discontinuities at 180° or 360°. This is appropriate for e.g. demodulating FM signals.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  The Complex to Arg type conversion (of course) works perfectly.   I was way overthinking the issue.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, could you also tell me how to define an 'exp(j(2*pifT+phase))' type of expression in gnuradio using c++ ?

Comment: @user1319236 Comments are not for asking new questions — please [post that separately](/questions/ask) and give more detail about how you want to use it. I'll still see it because I follow the [tag:gnuradio] tag.